# Updating an excel spreadsheet using OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have one web application where the database is MS Excel (just to keep few values, so we preferred excel than SQL).

I have written one common function for Save & Delete, based on the operation system will perform the action. Both are working fine.

The problem is, My cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() method does not returns any exception while executing (I verified next time when I load the sheet, I got the updated values in excel). But I cannot open the excel sheet as the worker process is attached on it. So I explicitly terminate the process (w3wp.exe). Now all the changes which I made thru application is not there.

How to resolve this...? Any idea

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to asnwer your question without seeing an example of your code. The first thing I would check is if you are closing your database connection. Something along these lines:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("connection string"))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        // do stuff
        cmd.ExecuteNotQuery();
    }
}
```

The `using` statement will close and dispose your command and connection once they go out of scope.
If this doesn't help, we're going to need more information.